# Bow that shoots lightning strike

Tags: java, bukkit

so im currently busy with a plugin that shoots a lightning strike as you see them come from the sky in minecraft, but horizontal from your bow with a set radius of 100 or something

```
package me.Pixel;

import org.bukkit.FireworkEffect;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.entity.LivingEntity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.weather.LightningStrikeEvent;
import org.bukkit.util.BlockIterator;

public class LightningShot implements Listener {

    public Main plugin;

    public LightningShot(Main instance) {
        this.plugin = instance;
    }

    public void onCast(Player p) {
        final BlockIterator blockNext = new BlockIterator(p);
        new Runnable() {
            public int timer = 0;

            public void run() {
                if(this.timer++ > 50) {
                    cancel();
                   }
                if(blockNext.hasNext()) {
                    cancel();
                }
                Block next = blockNext.next();
                try{
                    for(Entity e : LightningShot.this.plugin.getTargets.getTargetList(p, next.getLocation(), 3)) {
                        if(e instanceof LivingEntity) {
                    }
                    FireworkEffectPlayer.playToLocation(next.getLocation(), null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have right now, but where it says 'FireworkEffectPlayer.playToLocation(next.getLocation(), null);' im stuck i need to replace this with a code that makes the lightning come out of the bow when it fires.

This is the `Main` file

```
package me.Pixel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    public Main plugin;
    public List<String> spells = new ArrayList<String>();
    public getTargets getTargets = new getTargets();

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        plugin = this;
        getCommand("bow").setExecutor(new BowCommand());
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onClick(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        if(e.getAction() == Action.LEFT_CLICK_AIR || e.getAction() == Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
            Player p = e.getPlayer();
            ItemStack stack = p.getItemInHand();
            if(stack != null &&stack.getType() == Material.BOW && stack.hasItemMeta() && stack.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.RED + "Bow")) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this: http://youtu.be/riPIzITVp0c but instead of the snowball the arrow that comes out of the .
I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: change tag! `javascript !== java`

Comment: Are you sure it's possible to shoot lightning horizontal?  Have you found other examples of people doing this? I'd Google things like "minecraft shoot lightning" and see if you can find examples of horizontal lightning.

Comment: Check the video link i putted in

Comment: The video you linked to just spawns normal vertical lightning bolts every tick on an entity like a snowball. Lightning bolts are entities rendered by the client, therefore you can't make them horizontal or change their look with a server-side plugin.

Comment: Maybe Pixel would be satisfied with doing the same on an arrow entity then.

Comment: @AdrianSohn yea, thats what im trying to create, later i can add different bows, like a fire bow, or darkbow but for now i want this on the bows arrow. Could you help me?

Comment: @DavidS yea i would be satisfied, i want that effect on my magicbow his arrow

Comment: Have you tried using `World.strikeLightning(Location loc)` at the `Location` of an `Arrow` entity? You can use the `EntityShootBowEvent` to listen for any arrows being fired.

Comment: @AdrianSohn So, in my case where would i put it in my code? And do i need to delete parts for it?

Comment: You would listen to the `EntityShootBowEvent` by writing a new method just like you listen to the `PlayerInteractEvent` in your `Main` class (and listener). If you're referring to your first code snippet, I'm not sure how that is related to the arrow, partly because not all code is provided. `Runnable` does not have a `cancel()` method so I'm assuming you implemented that yourself, and I'm not sure what `getTargetList()` does. If it is related to the arrow lightning, could you please explain your code and add any remaining necessary parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an arrow have lightning strikes spawned at its location every single tick (or less often), you could create your own `BukkitRunnable` that keeps track of the `Arrow` entity and if the arrow lands, disappears or the task takes too long, cancels itself.

This is an example of such a `BukkitRunnable`:

```
public class LightningArrowTask extends BukkitRunnable {

    private Arrow arrow; // The arrow to spawn lightning at
    private int tick = 0; // The number of times the run() method has been invoked

    // The constructor that asks for an arrow entity
    public LightningArrowTask(Arrow arrow) {
        this.arrow = arrow;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // If the arrow no longer exists, has landed, or this task has been running for more than ~10 seconds (200 ticks)
        if (arrow == null || arrow.isOnGround() || tick++ > 20 * 10) {
            this.cancel(); // Cancel the task
        } else {
            arrow.getWorld().strikeLightning(arrow.getLocation()); // Otherwise, make lightning strike at the arrow's location
        }
    }
}
```

In your `EntityShootBowEvent` method, you could then use this class like so:

```
@EventHandler
public void onEntityShootBow(EntityShootBowEvent event) {
    if (event.getProjectile() instanceof Arrow) { // If the projectile shot is actually an arrow
        // Add your own conditions here ... such as the name of the bow etc.
        Arrow arrow = (Arrow) event.getProjectile(); // Cast
        // Create the LightningArrowTask BukkitRunnable with the arrow object, run it repeatedly every tick (with a 0 tick delay)
        new LightningArrowTask(arrow).runTaskTimer(this, 0, 1);
        // If you'd like the lightning to only be spawned every 2, 3, 5 etc. ticks, just change that last argument of the runTaskTimer method
    }
}
```

Comment: Ow man... You dont even know how grateful i am. But do i also need to do the text behind the //

Comment: And the LightningArrowTask, does that need to be another class? So it will be, LightningArrowTask.java in my file and LightningArrowTask.class in the exported file? And if yes, can i just delete LightningShot.java

Comment: Text behind `//` are just documentation, @Pixel, so they're not code, so you don't need them. You really must learn some Java programming if you're going to be able to mod Minecraft. BTW, it looks like you can just delete LightningShot because Adrian's solution doesn't use it.

Comment: You guys are lifesavers

Comment: Yeah, if my code works for you, `LightningShot.java` is not needed anymore, since your `Main` class already listens to the required events.

Comment: @AdrianSohn Okay the code works but I want to make multiple "Spells" for the bow, such as this one the LightningShot. But where can I made that? And I want to make a selector on the bow that you can "Scroll" through your spells by using the left mouse button. Also I would like to make multiple "MagicBows" like the LightningBow, Bow of Darkness (Just using alot of dark effects), FireBow. So thats my idea but how to make that because this is the first time me making this kind of plugin. And also i would like to make like some effects around the player when he holds a bow. Like some at MinePlex!

Comment: You might want to ask this in a new question and elaborate on what you mean by a scrollable selector on the bow. For multiple spells, you could either create a general "arrow spell task" class where you specify in the constructor what kind of effect you want to spawn at the arrow's location, or copy and paste the `LightningArrowTask.java` code into a new class and change the effect there. If you are at this point still stuck as to how you would implement any of this yourself, I would suggest going back and studying some java essentials before diving into plugin development.

Comment: @AdrianSohn Sorry for bothering xD and I will study more java (Actualy i am still studieng Java xD)